# How to specify the function is executing in batch mode?

Tags: c#

How can I specify in C# I am executing a function using the command prompt or in batch mode (what condition can I pass to show it is using the command propmt or batch mode)? What process do I need to initialize to check the function is executing in batch mode?

Comment: The C# function executes in the program. Are saying you need to know if the program was started from the command line, or want a program that runs only in command line mode?

Comment: Please rephrase your question - each of your "scenarios" occur concurrently - your application *always* uses environment variables, and I'm not sure what you mean by "batch mode" as opposed to being run via command prompt.

Comment: @preet sangha : Yes i want to specify or chek  program using command propmt or batch mode ( can i pass any condition  and call my code that will be started from commandprompt ).

Comment: @freedompeace : I  changed my question

Answer (score 2):

You can pass different arguments to your program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        //check the value of args[0]
    }
}
```

and when you run the program via command line, you can pass an argument to it:

```
D:\> MyProgram.exe -batch
```